# How to create a newick file from a cluster in R?

Tags: r, cluster-computing, hclust

This script below runs nicely to get the cluster with a huge data set, but I need to get the cluster into a newick file or a text file so I can export it from R to other editing programs but I can't find a way to get the hclust into a newick format, how can I do it?
I feel the new2phylo function may do the job but we did not manage to make it work.

I would really appreciate your help as we have searched everywhere and can't find a solution =(

```
datos <- read.table("morphclustersred.csv",header=T,sep="\t")
head(datos)
distfunc <- function(x) daisy(x,metric="gower")
d <- distfunc(datos)
hclustfunc <- function(x) hclust(x, method="complete")
fit <- hclustfunc(d)
plot(fit)
plot(fit, labels=datos$Species,main='Morphological Clustering')
rect.hclust(fit, k=5, border="red")
```

Comment: What's a newick file?

Comment: Have you checked Bioconductor or `library(sos); findFn("write newick")`?

Comment: Thanks so much Roman!! Got it working! Great!  the function is from ctc write(hc2Newick(fit), file='hclust.newick')

Comment: @Spacedman newick format (file) is [a way of representing graph-theoretical trees with edge lengths using parentheses and commas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format).

Answer (score 7):

You can do it by using `write.tree` function from `ape` package. Try this:

```
library(ape)
class(fit) # must be hclust class
my_tree <- as.phylo(fit) 
write.tree(phy=my_tree, file="exported_tree.newick") # look for the file in your working directory
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I've only ever managed to extract the .nwk formats from heatmaps by the following conversion steps:

- dendro --> hcclust --> phylo --> nwk

I know it's a bit of a hack, but here's the code:

```
# Heatmap of data frame 'data' saved as 'heat'
heat <- heatmap.2(as.matrix(data))

# Extract dendrograms for rows and columns from 'heat'
row.dendro <- heat$rowDendrogram
col.dendro <- heat$colDendrogram

# Convert dendrograms to nwk (via .hcclust and .phylo formats!)
as.hclust (row.dendro)  ->row.hcclust
as.phylo  (row.hcclust) ->row.phylo
write.tree(row.phylo)   ->row.nwk

as.hclust (col.dendro)  ->col.hcclust
as.phylo  (col.hcclust) ->col.phylo
write.tree(col.phylo)   ->col.nwk
```